# Forum Link instead of SE Link

Tags: wordpress, documentation, demo-site

Where would I put a "bug report" about a link pointing to the old forums, rather than here?  It's on the Wordpress demo page, at the very bottom of the page.

http://wpmaster.demo.civicrm.org/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asking here is a good step. I forwarded the info to someone on the core team who should know who to pass it on to. thanks for reporting it